# Display Terms and Conditions in Android Studio Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

i want display terms and conditions in activity. I want to put them in **big scrollable textView** but the problem is that in my string file i **must add Titles, paragraphs, link, with different font, font size, color etc**... How i can do that ?
At this moment i succeeded to do that with a big scrollView (12000px !;) with multiple textviews and multiple strings. How i can do better ? I'm bad in android development...
Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".controller.CguActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeTerms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12000dp">


        <TextView //TITLE IN BOLD ITALIC 19SP
            android:id="@+id/termsTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/title_terms"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font_bold_italic"
            android:textColor="@color/lightBlack"
            android:textSize="19sp"/>

        <TextView // ARTICLE TITLE IN BOLD 17SP
            android:id="@+id/article1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/termsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font_bold"
            android:text="@string/article1_terms"
            android:textColor="@color/lightBlack"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

       <TextView // PARAGRPAHE 1 IN REGULAR 15 SP
            android:id="@+id/para1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/article1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font_regular"
            android:text="@string/para1"
            android:textColor="@color/lightBlack"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

       ... // LOT OF ARTICLE TITLES, SUBTITLES AND PARAGRAPHS
    
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I can not to just put a link instead of all text. **I'm obligated** to write all in scroll view according to new laws in my country and to make the user accept **after he scroll all text**.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `wrap_content` instead of `12000dp` at

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeTerms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

You can format your String in HTML and display it in a `WebView` like [this](https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-show-html-string-in-android-textview-webview/).
You can also upload them to your webpage and show the whole webpage in your application that way.